# google.protobuf.Any field with grpc is always nil

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go, protocol-buffers

I am using gRPC with golang. I have a very simple proto definition and a gRPC service. The proto definition has a field in Endorsement of type *google/protobuf/any*. gRPC service is unable to map this field to input value and it's always getting initialised to nil

**proto definition**:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "service";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.consensus";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

package service;

service MyService {
  rpc Verify (Payload) returns (Response) {}
}

message Response {
  string policyId =1;
  string txnId =2;
}

message Endorsement {
  string endorserId=1;
  // This is being initialise to nil by gRPC
  google.protobuf.Any data = 2;
  string signature=3;
  bool isVerified=4;
}


message Payload {
  string policyId =1;
  string txnId =2;
  repeated Endorsement endorsements=3;
}
```

Using this, a simple gRPC service is implemented:

```
package service

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

type ServiceServerImpl struct {
}

func NewServiceServerImpl() *ServiceServerImpl {
    return &ServiceServerImpl{}
}

func (s *ServiceServerImpl) Verify(ctx context.Context, txnPayload *Payload) (*Response, error) {
    log.Printf("Got verification request: %s", txnPayload.TxnId)
    for _, endorsement := range txnPayload.Endorsements {
        j, err := endorsement.Data.UnmarshalNew()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Error while unmarshaling the endorsement")
        }
        if j==nil {
       //This gets printed as payload's endorsement data is always null for google/protobuf/any type
            log.Print("Data is null for endorsement")
        }
    }
    return &Response{TxnId: txnPayload.TxnId,  PolicyId: txnPayload.PolicyId}, nil
}
```

**Input Data:**

```
{
  "policyId": "9dd97b1e-b76f-4c49-b067-22143c954e75",
  "txnId": "231-4dc0-8e54-58231df6f0ce",
  "endorsements": [
    {
      "endorserId": "67e1dfbd-1716-4d91-94ec-83dde64e4b80",
      "data": {
        "type": "issueTx",
        "userId": 1,
        "transaction": {
            "amount": 10123.50
        }
    },
      "signature": "MEUCIBkooxG2uFZeSEeaf5Xh5hWLxcKGMxCZzfnPshOh22y2AiEAwVLAaGhccUv8UhgC291qNWtxrGawX2pPsI7UUA/7QLM=",
      "isVerified": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Client:

```
type Data struct {
    Type        string      `json:"type"`
    UserId      int16       `json:"userId"`
    Transaction Transaction `json:"transaction"`
}

type Transaction struct {
    Amount float32 `json:"amount"`
}

data := &Data{Type: "Buffer", UserId: 1, Transaction: Transaction{Amount: 10123.50}}
    byteData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not convert data input to bytes")
    }

    e := &any.Any{
        TypeUrl: "anything",
        Value:   byteData,
    }

    endosement := &Endorsement{EndorserId: "1", Signature: "MEUCIBkooxG2uFZeSEeaf5Xh5hWLxcKGMxCZzfnPshOh22y2AiEAwVLAaGhccUv8UhgC291qNWtxrGawX2pPsI7UUA/7QLM=", Data: e, IsVerified: false}
    var endosements = make([]*Endorsement, 1)
    endosements[0] = endosement
    t := &Payload{TxnId: "123", PolicyId: "456", Endorsements: endosements}

    response, err := c.Verify(context.Background(), t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when calling SayHello: %s", err)
    }
```

How should *google/protobuf/any* type be Unmarshal for unknown types?

```
m, err := e.Data.UnmarshalNew()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Error while unmarshaling the endorsement")
    }
```

> throws an error: s:"not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the package<sup>1</sup> documentation [Unmarshaling an Any](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.27.1/types/known/anypb#hdr-Unmarshaling_an_Any):

> `UnmarshalNew` uses the global type registry to resolve the message type and construct a new instance of that message to unmarshal into. In order for a message type to appear in the global registry, the Go type representing that protobuf message type must be linked into the Go binary. For messages generated by protoc-gen-go, this is achieved through **an import of the generated Go package representing a .proto file**.

The type registry is `protoregistry.GlobalTypes`. The type lookup is done using the `Any.TypeUrl` field, which is set to the concrete type's url by the gRPC client when marshalling the original message.

The confusing detail about `Any` is that it can be *any* protobuf message, but that protobuf message **must be defined somewhere**.

Your `.proto` file has no message definition that matches the `data` object in your input. It could be that this `Data` message is defined somewhere else (not in your own proto files), but irrespective of that you *have to import the Go package where the generated message is.*

Otherwise if the input doesn't come from an already defined proto message, you can add a message definition to your proto yourself, then use [`UnmarshalTo`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.27.1/types/known/anypb#UnmarshalTo):

```
// proto file
message Data {
    string type = 1;
    int user_id = 2;
    Transaction transaction = 3;
}

message Transaction {
    float amount = 1;
}
```

And then:

```
    for _, endorsement := range txnPayload.Endorsements {
        data := generated.Data{}
        err := endorsement.Data.UnmarshalTo(&data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Error while unmarshaling the endorsement")
        }
    }
```

---

If you only need an arbitrary sequence of bytes, i.e. a truly unknown type, then use the proto type `bytes` and treat it as a JSON payload.

Model it as a Go struct:

```golang
type Data struct {
    Type     string `json:"type"`
    UserID   int    `json:"userId"`
    Transaction struct{
        Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
    } `json:"transaction"`

}
```

Or as a `map[string]interface{}` if clients could be sending literally anything.

Then in your handler func:

```golang
    for _, endorsement := range txnPayload.Endorsements {
        data := Data{} // or `map[string]interface{}`
        err := json.Unmarshal(endorsement.Data, &data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Error while unmarshaling the endorsement")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As you know `google.protobuf.Any` is messageType, so when you didn't set any value for it, It will be nil.

You must unmarshal your data with your struct, see code below from example of [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/any.proto#L77-L88)

```
      // marshal any
      foo := &pb.Foo{...}
      any, err := anypb.New(foo)
      if err != nil {
        ...
      }
      // unmarshal any 
      foo := &pb.Foo{}
      if err := any.UnmarshalTo(foo); err != nil {
        ...
      }
```

Or I think you can use it with pointer interface **(&interface{})**
like this :

```
      d := &interface{}{}
      if err := endorsement.Data.UnmarshalTo(d); err != nil {
        ...
      }
```

Comment: @NitishBhardwaj for this reason I suggest you to use interface, also you can use map[string]interface{}